# Best Practice for Django Mixins?

Tags: python, django, django-views, coding-style, mixins

I'm working on a Django project and creating a custom mixin, specifically a `MessagesMixin` for handling success and error messages. I'm using it with `CreateView` and `UpdateView`. **I'm wondering about the best practice regarding the mixin's dependency on the view it is mixed into??.**

I have created a two version of `MessagesMixin`, which one is the correct answer ???

###### Version 1:

```py
class MessagesMixin:
    success_message = None
    fail_message = None
    fail_redirect_url = None

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        if self.success_message:
            messages.success(self.request, self.success_message.format(self.object))
        return response

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        super().form_invalid(form)
        if self.success_message:
            messages.error(self.request, self.fail_message.format(self.object))
        return redirect(self.fail_redirect_url)
```

###### Version 2:

```py
class MessagesMixin(ModelFormMixin, View):
    success_message = None
    fail_message = None
    fail_redirect_url = None

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        if self.success_message:
            messages.success(self.request, self.success_message.format(self.object))
        return response

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        super().form_invalid(form)
        if self.success_message:
            messages.error(self.request, self.fail_message.format(self.object))
        return redirect(self.fail_redirect_url)
```

Comment: The mixin shouldn't inherit from `View`, but if it is a variation of `ModelFormMixin` that needs the other [non-overridden methods](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/4.2/django.views.generic.edit/ModelFormMixin/) from that mixin then it should inherit from it. So I think the right answer is probably `class MessagesMixin(ModelFormMixin)`

Comment: As i use the MessagesMixin in a view that inherits from ```FormMixin``` or ```View```, the ```request``` object is automatically available as an argument in the methods of my view. So i don't need to explicitly include it in the mixin ?